# Reactjs Hooks. How to keep data after I apply filter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am fetching an array of objects and I want to apply multiple filters.
Following the scenario: Open popover and selected "cat" should show all the cats after pressing "APPLY", close the popover -> come back to filters -> "dog" is checked -> select and filter AGAIN by type "cat" AND by name "foxy" -> show all the cats with name "foxy". Seems like the data fetch from begin is not keeped in memory. Yes, because when I filter it, I set it by filters, but don't know how to refilter it.

Can you guide me and explain me how to do it? Thanks!

https://codesandbox.io/s/keep-data-after-i-apply-first-filter-f0cdj

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditions in `Array.filter` :

```js
  const handleFilteredData = () => {
    setData(creaturesData.filter(c=>filters.type.includes(c.type) || filters.name.includes(c.name)))
  };
```

But you have to pass the name of types to filters instead of ID:

```js
  const handleTypeCheck = (e) => {
    const id = e.target.name;

    console.log(typeof id);
    const updatedData = data.map((item) => {
      return item.type === id ? { ...item, checked: !item.checked } : item;
    });
    setData(updatedData);
  };
```

Comment: Yes, you are right but this doesn't resolve my problem. When I open again the popup, filter is not active. I mean, if first time I check "cat" and press Apply, second time when I press Filters, "cat" is not checked and if I select "dog", of course there is no "dogs" in previously data filtered.

Comment: Seems like I resolv it. I changed the structure of data. From main app I'm sending the filters to every component filter, and if is array I will check it.

Comment: I updated my problem. Can you suggest me a solution?